# how to get the view of android device to make a screenshot application?

Tags: android

I want to make a screenshot android application[not rooted] but i have some problems

the following code will show the view of any application and return bitmap of the screen

```
    public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

but i want to make the above code in a service not in activity because when i click on 
notification, it will capture the screen, not to go to another activity

the problem is findViewById used in activity not in a service.

can you please let me know how Can i do this or any other solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to take screenshots of arbitrary screens on the device outside of your app for security reasons.

If the device is rooted, you can attempt to parse the framebuffer and get the bitmap from that.

Comment: can i know how the screenshot applications from google store runs on unrooted device ?

Comment: @AhmedMohamedSayed Most of them don't. Those that do use hacks and bugs that don't work consistently.